# Java - CodeName One: not finding symbole fileInput/Output

Tags: java, file-io, copy, codenameone, java-io

I'm trying to copy an image with java in a codename One project , this is the code which gives correct copy of the image:

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.gui;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
/**
 *
 * @author Emel
 */
public class NewMain {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
          throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {
        // TODO code application logic here

    InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
            is = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/Emel/AppData/Local/Temp/temp8255862222083205111..png"));
            os = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/wamp64/www/PiWeb1/TeamFlags/mpmppp.png"));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
    }

}
```

the code works perfectly when i put it in a main java class (it only works when i run the mainclass ) but when i build the project the build fails and the output show this error :

> `C:\Users\Emel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PIMOBILE\Mobile\src\com\mycompany\gui\NewMain.java:8:
>   error: cannot find symbol import java.io.File;   symbol:   class File 
>   location: package java.io
>   C:\Users\Emel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PIMOBILE\Mobile\src\com\mycompany\gui\NewMain.java:9:
>   error: cannot find symbol import java.io.FileInputStream;   symbol:
>   class FileInputStream   location: package java.io
>   C:\Users\Emel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PIMOBILE\Mobile\src\com\mycompany\gui\NewMain.java:10:
>   error: cannot find symbol import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
>   symbol:   class FileNotFoundException   location: package java.io
>   C:\Users\Emel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PIMOBILE\Mobile\src\com\mycompany\gui\NewMain.java:11:
>   error: cannot find symbol import java.io.FileOutputStream;   symbol:
>   class FileOutputStream   location: package java.io
>   C:\Users\Emel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PIMOBILE\Mobile\src\com\mycompany\gui\NewMain.java:25:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>             throws FileNotFoundException, IOException    symbol:   class FileNotFoundException   location: class NewMain
>   C:\Users\Emel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PIMOBILE\Mobile\src\com\mycompagny\Service\ServiceEquipe.java:38:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               is = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Emel/AppData/Local/Temp/temp8255862222083205111..png");
>   symbol:   class FileInputStream   location: class ServiceEquipe
>   C:\Users\Emel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PIMOBILE\Mobile\src\com\mycompagny\Service\ServiceEquipe.java:39:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               os = new FileOutputStream(   symbol:   class FileOutputStream   location: class ServiceEquipe
>   C:\Users\Emel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PIMOBILE\Mobile\src\com\mycompany\gui\NewMain.java:31:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               is = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/Emel/AppData/Local/Temp/temp8255862222083205111..png"));
>   symbol:   class FileInputStream   location: class NewMain
>   C:\Users\Emel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PIMOBILE\Mobile\src\com\mycompany\gui\NewMain.java:31:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               is = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/Emel/AppData/Local/Temp/temp8255862222083205111..png"));
>   symbol:   class File   location: class NewMain
>   C:\Users\Emel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PIMOBILE\Mobile\src\com\mycompany\gui\NewMain.java:32:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               os = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/wamp64/www/PiWeb1/TeamFlags/mpmppp.png"));   symbol:   class
>   FileOutputStream   location: class NewMain
>   C:\Users\Emel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PIMOBILE\Mobile\src\com\mycompany\gui\NewMain.java:32:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>               os = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/wamp64/www/PiWeb1/TeamFlags/mpmppp.png"));   symbol:   class
>   File   location: class NewMain Note:
>   C:\Users\Emel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PIMOBILE\Mobile\src\com\mycompagny\Service\ServiceEquipe.java
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: C:\Users\Emel\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PIMOBILE\Mobile\src\com\mycompagny\Service\ServiceEquipe.java
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:unchecked for details. 11 errors

`

Now i need to put that code block into a method to recall it, i tried to do that in different ways but i failed it only works when i use it in a main class.

PS1: when i delete that main class from my project the build succeed.

PS2: the solution works perfectly in a normal java project so i think the problem is due to codename One.

Im using netbeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.io.File, java.io.FileInputStream, java.io.FileNotFoundException & 
java.io.FileOutputStream` don't exist in Codename One.

There is a long explanation [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-we-dont-support-the-full-java-api.html).

There are several reasons but these specific API's won't act correctly on a mobile device where your app needs to run in isolation from other processes and has limited/restricted access. E.g. in your case it's pretty obvious the `C:` path won't exist on Android or iOS both of which are Unix derivatives (Linux/BSD).

You need to use `FileSystemStorage` or `Storage` there is a section about those in [the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/files-storage-networking.html).